# How to use XMLType in a SQL*Loader control file?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader, xmltype

I have a csvfile, which contains a column of XML data. A sample record of the csv look like:

```
1,,,<capacidade><numfields>3</numfields><template>1</template><F1><name lang="pt">Apple</name></F1></capacidade>
```

I'd like to use SQL*Loader to import all the data into Oracle; I defined the ctl file as follows:

```
LOAD DATA
 CHARACTERSET UTF8
 INFILE '/home/db2inst1/result.csv'
 CONTINUEIF NEXT(1:1) = '#'
 INTO TABLE "TEST"."T_DATA_TEMP"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY','
(   "ID" 
  , "SOURCE" 
  , "CATEGORY" 
  , "RAWDATA"
 )
```

Wen running this, the error log shows that the column of RAWDATA is treated as CHARACTER data type. How can I define the RAWDATA to be a XMLType in this case so that it can be correctly insert into the Oracle?

Comment: i think you have to create a seperate xml file for the rawdata see https://community.oracle.com/message/5282033

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Add a comma at the end of xml so as to mark a delimiter(can't use whitespace as xml may contain spaces in between)

then create your ctl file like below

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE "TEST"."T_DATA_TEMP" fields OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( ID terminated by "," ,
 SOURCE terminated by ",", 
 CATEGORY terminated by ",", 
 RAWDATA char(4000) terminated by ","
 )
```